# weil ich es mir wert bin

Tags: grammaticality

there is a L'oreal's ad phrase "...weil ich es mir wert bin".
And what really breaks my brain is the question... what are the subject and the object here?

The initial slogan is a dependent clause. So normally, as a main clause, it should be like "Ich bin es mir wert" (omg what have I just written?)

Ok, subject is "ich" the verb is "bin". Then what is "es" here? Is it in Nominativ or Akkusativ? What is "wert"? An adjective or a verb?

Could you please explain the role of each word in the clause ", weil ich es mir wert bin"?

Comment: For historical context and better grammatical understanding the original english slogan is "Because I'm Worth It" and was invented over 40 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment "Weil ich es mir wert bin" is a translation of the old L'oreal ad phrase "Because I'm Worth It".

Here is the text of the first commercial from the 70s ([link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6DHRFuCEwA))

> I use the most expensive hair color in the world. Preference by
>   L'Oréal. It' not that I care about money. It's that I care about my
>   hair. It's not just the color. I expect great color. Actually, I don't
>   mind spending more for L'Oréal. Because I'm Worth It.

The commercial itself says that L'Oréals products weren't cheap. There were other cheaper brands. But the results of using them made it worth. So "Because I'm worth it" is the short answer to some kind of question like "Why should I spend more money on products by L'Oréal than buying cheaper ones?" with the longer answer "Because the results will be so much better. And therefore I will gladly spend more money, because my body / my looks are worth to spend more."

But lets get back to the german sentence and your question.

- Weil - [Konjunktion](https://easy-deutsch.de/satzbau/nebensatz/kausalsatz-weil-da/), start of the dependent clause
- ich - Subjekt
- es - Objekt (Akkusativ) [Pronomen](https://easy-deutsch.de/verben/verben-mit-es/), refering to
  another sentence as mentioned above
- mir - [Reflexivpronomen](http://donnerwetter.kielikeskus.helsinki.fi/DVG/Pronomen/Pronomen-Regeln/ReflexPron/deutsch.htm) (Dativ), refering
  to Ich
- wert - Adjektiv
- bin - Verb

Comment: I know why I am confused. Because of "mir". "Because I'm Worth It" sounds ok for me, but is it possible to insert into this phrase "to me" or something similar? (btw English is not my native language too)

Comment: will it mean the same and will it be grammatically correct, if I say "weil es mir wert ist"?

Answer (score 2):

> Ihre Gehaltsforderung ist ziemlich hoch! – Ich bin es wert.

*Es* ist *das Gehalt* in this case.

> Na gut, sie können ja auch was, das ist es mir wert.

*Mir* is the person who evaluates the value.

That slogan

> …, weil ich es mir wert bin.

does not give an answer what *es* might be. The product's uncompetetively high price? *Mir* is still the person who evaluates this price – the person who hears that slogan.